# Use loopback token for authentication of socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, loopbackjs

I'm working with loopback 2.0 and socket.io 1.0.6.

I'd like to use loopback authentication method for authentication of socket.io.

I found the method to authenticate users in loopback/lib/middleware/token.js. https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/lib/middleware/token.js

Then I write like below:

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var ioapp = module.exports = socketio;

function socketio(server) {
  var io = require('socket.io')(server);

  // auth
  io.use(function(socket, next) {
    loopback.token()(socket.request, null, next);
  });

  // listeners
  ...

  return io;
};
```

But actually I won't work and causes error like this.

```
/Users/.../project_root/node_modules/loopback/lib/models/access-token.js:201
    id = req.param(params[i]);
             ^
TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'param'
    at tokenIdForRequest (/Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/node_modules/loopback/lib/models/access-token.js:201:14)
    at Function.AccessToken.findForRequest (/Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/node_modules/loopback/lib/models/access-token.js:123:12)
    at /Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/node_modules/loopback/lib/middleware/token.js:53:16
    at Array.0 (/Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/server/socket.js:15:28)
    at run (/Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:114:11)
    at Namespace.run (/Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:126:3)
    at Namespace.add (/Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:155:8)
    at Client.connect (/Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:67:20)
    at Server.onconnection (/Users/ksuzuki/Projects/appsocially/repo/chat-center/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:309:10)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

I guess this is because I pass the wrong object type to loopback.token() method.

Comment: That request object should be the express request object. The access token id is being pulled from `req.params` to check to see if it's a valid token.

Answer (score 1):

Well I believe Loopback token is built to be used with express request object. In the latest version(2.x) you could use it if you override `AccessToken.findForRequest` and implement it you yourself.

But there's another approach to this which is covered in [the official documentation](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Realtime-socket-io.html#on-the-server):

Basically it suggest using [`socketio-auth`](https://github.com/facundoolano/socketio-auth)(Which "provides hooks to implement authentication in socket.io without using querystrings to send credentials, which is not a good security practice") and using AccessToken model directly.

I put the code here with a little bit of simplification:

On server-side:

```
app.io = require('socket.io')(app.start());
require('socketio-auth')(app.io, {
  authenticate: function (socket, value, callback) {

      var AccessToken = app.models.AccessToken;
      //get credentials sent by the client
      var token = AccessToken.count({
        userId: value.userId,
        id: value.id,
      }, callback);  
    }
});
```

On client-side:

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
    // You should have retrieved tokenId/userId by calling user.login and
    // saving it in cookies or localStorage.
    socket.emit('authentication', {id: tokenId, userId: userId });
});
```